# Find the edges size of a regular triangular pyramid with a given volume, which has the smallest sum of edges.

Tags: optimization, triangles

$a\\$ - edge length at the base of the pyramid.

$b\\$ - length of the side edges of the pyramid.

$V\\$ = $const\\$.

I minimize: $3a+3b->min\\$

$V=\frac{1}{3}Sh\\$

$h=\sqrt{b^2-\frac{1}{3}a^2}\\$

$S=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a^2\\$

$V=\frac{1}{3}*\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a^2*\sqrt{b^2-\frac{1}{3}a^2}\\$ - from here I expressed the parameter $b\\$ and substituted in $3a+3b->min\\$

$b=\sqrt\frac{V^2+\frac{3a^6}{432}}{\frac{3a^4}{144}}\\$

After substitution, I found the derivative and equated it to zero, but the derivative was too complex, it seems to me that I am doing something wrong.

Derivative:
$3+\frac{a^6-288V^2}{a^5*\sqrt{\frac{48V^2}{a^4}+\frac{a^2}{3}}}=0\\$

How to express $a\\$ from here?

Comment: How do you get the formula for $h$?

Comment: By the Pythagorean theorem: $h^2=b^2-(\frac{2}{3}*\frac{\sqrt{3}a}{2})^2\\$

Comment: Ok, i get $$b=\sqrt{\frac{144V^2}{3a^4}+\frac{1}{3}a^2}$$

Comment: I get this too. $b=\sqrt\frac{V^2+\frac{3a^6}{432}}{\frac{3a^4}{144}} = \sqrt{\frac{144V^2}{3a^4}+\frac{a^2}{3}}\\$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As brought up in the comments, we have that

$$
b=\sqrt{\frac{144{V^2}}{3a^4}+\frac{1}{3}a^2}.
$$

You wish to minimize the function

$$
f(a)=a+\sqrt{\frac{144{V^2}}{3a^4}+\frac{1}{3}a^2}
$$

by equating the derivative to zero (note that I dropped the scaling multiplication by $3$, since it does not affect the minimizer). Introducing the notation $k=144V^2/3$ and $m=1/3$, the derivative of $f$ is

$$
f'(a)=1-\frac{\big(\frac{2k}{a^5}-ma\big)}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{a^4}+ma^2}}
$$

Equate this to zero, and get

$$
\sqrt{\frac{k}{a^4}+ma^2}=\frac{2k}{a^5}-ma
$$

Multiply both sides by $a^5$:

$$
\sqrt{ka^6+ma^{12}}=2k-ma^6.
$$

Introduce the notation $x\equiv{a^6}$, and this becomes

$$
\sqrt{mx^2+kx}=2k-mx.
$$

Square both sides (at this point we need to be careful about choosing the right signs):

$$
m(1-m)x^2+k(1+4m)x-4k^2=0.
$$

Solve with the quadratic formula (choose the proper sign), and substitute $x=a^6$ to get the final answer.